# Ruby, Nokogiri: how do i ensure UTF8 throughout nokogiri parsing, erb template, and encoding HTML file

Tags: html, ruby, parsing, utf-8, nokogiri

I finally managed to parse parts of a website:

```
get '/' do
  url = '<website>'
  data = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  @rows = data.css("td[valign=top] table tr") 
  erb :muster
end
```

Now I am trying to extract a certain line in my view. Therefore i put in my HTML code:

```
<%= @rows[2] %>
```

And it actually returns the code, but it has problems with UTF8:

```
<td class="class_name">&nbsp;</td>
```

instead it says

```
<td class="class_name">�</td>
```

How do I ensure UTF8 during nokogiri parsing, erb, and HTML generation?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

See: http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html#encoding

It looks like in your case, the document is declaring that it's encoded using iso8859:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1">
```

You can do the following to force Nokogiri to treat the stream as UTF-8:

```
data = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url), nil, Encoding::UTF_8.to_s)
```

Comment: Maybe the website you're hitting is not UTF-8, what's the URL?

Comment: Updated my answer to show how you can force nokogiri to use UTF-8

Comment: If you're doing a fragment, you can just do `Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html, Encoding::UTF_8.to_s)`

Comment: This doesn't seem to be enough , it seems like Nokogiri doesn't handle it as expected. I use the following to provide the protection I need " doc = Nokogiri::HTML( email.try(:force_encoding,'ISO-8859-1').try(:encode,'UTF-8').to_s )".

Comment: doc.text works either way , but doc.text.match(/string/) doesn't , unless you add the extra force_encoding.